# camel cxf uri option property.XXX to set http client timeout

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, talend

It is possible to set client timeout via camel cxf uri options?

There is possibility to set `cxf://someAddress?[options]`, where options can be properties.XXX.
It is possible to set somehow http client receive timeout?

I tried many of them (found in source code or via google), but no one works:

```
properties.com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout
properties.com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout
properties.javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout
properties.org.apache.cxf.jms.client.timeout
properties.org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.SO_TIMEOUT
properties.conduit.client.ReceiveTimeout
properties.org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.client.ReceiveTimeout
properties.http-conf:client.ReceiveTimeout
properties.HTTPClientPolicy.ReceiveTimeout
properties.org.apache.cxf.http.conduits.client.ReceiveTimeout
properties.org.apache.cxf.http.conduit.client.ReceiveTimeout
properties.org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy.ReceiveTimeout
```

I know it is possible with sprinx xml, but I want it configurable via Talend context.

I also know that I can configure cxf client via CxfEndpointConfigurer bean, but camel 2.13 (upgrade is not possible) does not have configureClient method.

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this document](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) you can configure HTTP Client to set timeout

```
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort.http-conduit">
  <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive"
                    MaxRetransmits="1"
                    AllowChunking="false" 
                    ConnectionTimeout="60000"
                    ReceiveTimeout="60000"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Comment: Yes, but timeout is defined as constant. There is a possibility to use osgi or camel property placeholders, that can be defined as reference to external property file, but they are also constants. And I want to have timeout filled from Talend actual context via java. I also looked at PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean and PropertiesComponent but I don't know what exactly it can be used and if it is possible to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a RouteBuilder, use the java variable in your route.

Tyr do something like this:

```
from("cxf://someAddress?[options]?timeout=${yourTimeOutVariable}")
```

Comment: Hi. Timeout is unknown parameter for cxf component. Route will not start. I tried this with properties.XXX parameter, but I don't know what name it has (or it is even possible).